# Пустые строки DataGrid заполняются при прокрутке

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Добавляю новые строки нажатием на кнопку. В обработке нажатия - добавление пустой строки в DataTable, являющейся ItemsSource для dataGrid.Прокручиваю вверх-вниз - пустые строки заполняются данными из верхних строк, при этом в DataTable строки пустые, как и надо. Что происходит?

[image: До прокрутки]

[image: После прокрутки]

Comment: Добавьте больше информации (кода).

Comment: А виртуализация включена? Может с этим какие-то проблемы.

Comment: У вас есть возможность сделать MCVE?

Comment: @dm.dymov Спасибо, именно с этим. Отключила - всё нормально.